# I wanna set type's number to id of select tag

Tags: python, html, django

I wanna set type's number to id of select tag.
My ideal html in browser is

```
 <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
      <option value="0">---</option>
      <option value="1">a</option>
      <option value="2">b</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type1">
      <option value="1">a1</option>
      <option value="2">a2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type" id="type2">
      <option value="5">b1</option>
      <option value="6">b2</option>
    </select>
```

Now actual html in browse is

```
   <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
            <option>---</option>  
            <option>a</option> 
            <option>b</option>  
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">a1</option>   
        <option value="2">a2</option>   
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="5">---</option>
        <option value="6">b1</option>
        <option value="7">b2</option>  
    </select>
```

id="type" of  does not have each number but I do not know how to add these number by using Django's template.
I wrote in index.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>


    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id=type>
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{ counter }}">{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

What should I write it?How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) instead of counter:

```
{% for key, values in preprocessed %}
<select name="type" id=type{{forloop.counter}}>
  {% for counter, value in values %}
  <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ value }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>


    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
        <select name="type" id=type-{{ key }}>
        {% forvalue in values %}
            <option value="{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Its better to use your key in type so that you can easily reference it later. Also no need to a separate counter variable. Django template tags provide forloop.counter for that purpose. forloop.counter0 starts the counter index with 0 and forloop.counter starts the counter index with 1. Hope this clears your doubt.

Ref - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for